Custom circular Countdown progressbar in Qt widget C++
I want a circular time counter to display the remaining time of a process that looks like the figure below
I use Qty 6.6.3 and Qty widgets
If anyone has an idea to do this, I would appreciate it if you could help me.

I wrote the code similar to what I want, but this model is loading and the user cannot see the remaining time.

CircleLoadingWidget.cpp
#include <QtGui/qpainter.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include "circle_loading_widget.h"


CircleLoadingWidget::CircleLoadingWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , background(Qt::transparent)
    , timerId(0)
{
}


CircleLoadingWidget::~CircleLoadingWidget()
{
}


void CircleLoadingWidget::setColors(const QList<QColor> &colors)
{
    this->colors = colors;
    if (timerId) {
        update();
    }
}


QColor CircleLoadingWidget::getColor(int i)
{
    if (colors.size() > i) {
        return colors.at(i);
    } else {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return QColor("#dc322f");
        case 1:
            return QColor("#268bd2");
        default:
            return QColor("#90CAF9");
        }
    }
}


void CircleLoadingWidget::setBackground(const QBrush &background)
{
    this->background = background;
    if (timerId) {
        update();
    }
}


void CircleLoadingWidget::start()
{
    if (!timerId) {
        timerId = startTimer(1000 / 60);
        timer.restart();
    }
}


void CircleLoadingWidget::stop()
{
    if (timerId) {
        killTimer(timerId);
        timerId = 0;
    }
}


void CircleLoadingWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
    qint64 msecs = timer.elapsed();
    msecs %= 5000;
    bool inverted;
    if (msecs > 2500) {
        msecs = msecs - 2500;
        inverted = true;
    } else {
        inverted = false;
    }
    QEasingCurve headCurve(QEasingCurve::OutQuart);
    QEasingCurve tailCurve(QEasingCurve::InQuad);

    QRect r0 = rect();
    if (r0.width() > r0.height()) {
        r0.setWidth(r0.height());
    } else {
        r0.setHeight(r0.width());
    }
    r0.moveCenter(rect().center());
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(background);
    painter.setPen(background.color());
    painter.drawRect(rect());
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
        qreal k1 = qMin(msecs / (1000.0 + 1000.0 / 10 * i), 1.0);
        qreal k2 = qMin(msecs / (1500.0 + 1000.0 / 10 * i), 1.0);
        if (qFuzzyCompare(k1, k2)) {
            continue;
        }

        qreal headAngle, tailAngle, spanAngle;
        if (inverted) {
            headAngle = 90 - headCurve.valueForProgress(k1) * 360;
            tailAngle = 90 - tailCurve.valueForProgress(k2) * 360;
        } else {
            headAngle = headCurve.valueForProgress(k1) * 360 + 90;
            tailAngle = tailCurve.valueForProgress(k2) * 360 + 90;
        }
        spanAngle =  tailAngle - headAngle;

        QRect r1 = r0 ;
        r1.setSize(r0.size() * (0.1 * (10 - i)));
        r1.moveCenter(r0.center());
        QRect r2 = r0;
        r2.setSize(r0.size() * (0.1 * (9 - i) + 0.01));
        r2.moveCenter(r0.center());

        qreal l1 = 1.0 - headCurve.valueForProgress(k1);
        qreal l3 = tailCurve.valueForProgress(k1);
        qreal l2 = 1.0 - l1 - l3;

        painter.setBrush(getColor(0));
        painter.drawPie(r1, headAngle * 16, spanAngle * 16 * l1 * 0.9);
        painter.setBrush(background);
        painter.drawPie(r2, headAngle * 16, spanAngle * 16 * l1 * 0.9);

        painter.setBrush(getColor(1));
        painter.drawPie(r1, headAngle * 16 + spanAngle * 16 * l1, spanAngle * 16 * l2 * 0.9);
        painter.setBrush(background);
        painter.drawPie(r2, headAngle * 16 + spanAngle * 16 * l1, spanAngle * 16 * l2 * 0.9);

        painter.setBrush(getColor(2));
        painter.drawPie(r1, headAngle * 16 + spanAngle * 16 * (l1 + l2), spanAngle * 16 * l3 * 0.9);
        painter.setBrush(background);
        painter.drawPie(r2, headAngle * 16 + spanAngle * 16 * (l1 + l2), spanAngle * 16 * l3 * 0.9);
    }
}



void CircleLoadingWidget::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if (event->timerId() != timerId) {
        QWidget::timerEvent(event);
        return;
    }
    update();
}


CircleLoadingWidget.h
#ifndef CIRCLELOADINGWIDGET_H
#define CIRCLELOADINGWIDGET_H

#include <QtCore/qtimer.h>
#include <QtCore/qelapsedtimer.h>
#include <QtCore/qeasingcurve.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qwidget.h>


class CircleLoadingWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CircleLoadingWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~CircleLoadingWidget() override;
public:
    void setColors(const QList<QColor> &colors);
    void setBackground(const QBrush &background);
    void start();
    void stop();
protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
    virtual void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) override;
private:
    QColor getColor(int i);
private:
    QList<QColor> colors;
    QBrush background;
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    int timerId;
};


#endif // CIRCLELOADINGWIDGET_H


the result is like this (it has loading animation and user can not see the remaining time and proccess):
 

Can you clarify what does "but this model is loading and the user cannot see the remaining time" mean?

Yes, I will definitely edit my question so that you understand it better

Where is the text supposed to come from? i don't see any in yout paint. Model?

The result you get is very different from the first image, so it's not entirely clear what goal you want to achieve. Actually for the first image I would do the following:
class Gauge: public QWidget
{
public:
    Gauge(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {}
    
    void setValue(int value)
    {
        if (value != m_value) {
            m_value = qBound(0, value, 100);
            update();
        }
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        painter.fillRect(rect(), Qt::white);
        
        int size = qMin(width(), height()) - 40;
        QRectF rect(20, 20, size, size);
        
        QPen pen(QColor::fromString("#eaeaea"), 20, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap);
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.drawEllipse(rect);
        
        pen.setColor(QColor::fromString("#4a62ad"));
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.drawArc(rect, 90 * 16, -m_value * 16 * 3.6);
        
        painter.setPen(QColor::fromString("#333333"));
        QFont font = painter.font();
        font.setBold(true);
        font.setPointSize(size / 5);
        painter.setFont(font);
        painter.drawText(rect, Qt::AlignCenter, QString::number(m_value) + "%");
    }

private:
    int m_value{0};
};

That probably should look like this:


Very practical and comfortable , Thanks.
